# Problem with & in the reference

Tags: cross-referencing, symbols

In BibDesk I introduced a book reference and I added in the publisher the character & and this is the message after compiling document

! Misplaced alignment tab character &.

I removed the & from BibDesk and saved but the message of error remains. I tried to remove the citation at all, but still the error remains, I don't know what to do

Comment: Escape it and put it in braces in your bibtex file, like so: `{\&}`Also, flush your auxiliary files (*.aux and *.bbl) and rerun bibtex.

Comment: But the problem is that the error remain even if I completely deleted the reference from my bibdesk library

Comment: And remove the `.aux` file and maybe some other additional files before the next LaTeX run.

Comment: Remove the `.bbl` file & recompile.

Comment: Thanks, what a fool I am.. why didn't I think of it before!!! I guess I was freaking out :)